# JSON Array to Array List using c#

Tags: c#, json, firebase, json.net

I'm trying to convert JSON to list, please anyone can help me.

```
public class User
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String imageURL { get; set; }
    public String search { get; set; }
    public String status { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
}



List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(resp.Body);

JSON
{
    "KfWE8S9jWJdWnAZEbOtHTtisNwO2":
        {"id":"KfWE8S9jWJdWnAZEbOtHTtisNwO2"
        ,"imageURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bchat-af5e5.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1542785437375.jpg?alt=media&token=be1ce806-fecf-4081-9dad-f0a20e5d8489"
        ,"search":"rene vizconde"
        ,"status":"online"
        ,"username":"Rene Vizconde"},
    "ScpDnyQCyKemXSgdo3jEvZFNxY83":
        {"id":"ScpDnyQCyKemXSgdo3jEvZFNxY83"
        ,"imageURL":"default"
        ,"search":"yeli potpot"
        ,"status":"offline"
        ,"username":"Yeli Potpot"},
    "cnPYOdHYWaaLDQmchELLvw85DBf1":
        {"id":"cnPYOdHYWaaLDQmchELLvw85DBf1"
        ,"imageURL":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHilM1ke9pZePBJTobMTcktggiw-UywdqAIpf-VX9nqecKl6b4wQ"
        ,"search":"bards disc"
        ,"status":"offline"
        ,"username":"Bards Disc"},
    "tWTbllTxaVM9WQnsNwnBgc3ixLM2":
        {"id":"tWTbllTxaVM9WQnsNwnBgc3ixLM2"
        ,"imageURL":"default"
        ,"search":"renz angelo"
        ,"status":"offline"
        ,"username":"Renz Angelo"}
    }
```

Comment: is anything wrong with my answer that you just unchecked tick. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your JSON. Altough its structure is "syntaxly" correct, it was badly designed.

You're naming member of the JSON using ids, and then refers to that ID in each object of thoses members.

Don't Repeat Yourself.

Since the name of the members are dynamic, you can't use that root object to deserialize the JSON. (which is NOT a `List<User>`, there is no list in that JSON, but objects)

Consider using this structure rather (notice the brackets to create an array of objects)

```
[
    {
        "id":"KfWE8S9jWJdWnAZEbOtHTtisNwO2"
        ,"imageURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bchat-af5e5.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1542785437375.jpg?alt=media&token=be1ce806-fecf-4081-9dad-f0a20e5d8489"
        ,"search":"rene vizconde"
        ,"status":"online"
        ,"username":"Rene Vizconde"
    },
    {
        "id":"ScpDnyQCyKemXSgdo3jEvZFNxY83"
        ,"imageURL":"default"
        ,"search":"yeli potpot"
        ,"status":"offline"
        ,"username":"Yeli Potpot"
    },
    {
        "id":"cnPYOdHYWaaLDQmchELLvw85DBf1"
        ,"imageURL":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHilM1ke9pZePBJTobMTcktggiw-UywdqAIpf-VX9nqecKl6b4wQ"
        ,"search":"bards disc"
        ,"status":"offline"
        ,"username":"Bards Disc"
    },
    {
        "id":"tWTbllTxaVM9WQnsNwnBgc3ixLM2"
        ,"imageURL":"default"
        ,"search":"renz angelo"
        ,"status":"offline"
        ,"username":"Renz Angelo"
    }
]
```

Comment: Using the ID as a key is quite normal once you know that this data structure comes from the Firebase Realtime Database, a NoSQL database that stores JSON data. The keys are user IDs, and using them as keys allows you to efficiently look up a user by their ID. It's quite similar to a primary key in relational databases in that sense. In your proposed structure you'd have to scan the entire array, which in the case of Firebase lives on a server. In the original JSON structure, you can perform a direct lookup based on the user id.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply deserialize your json into `Dictionary<string, User>` instead of `List<User>`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, User>>(resp.Body);

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            User user = item.Value;

            Console.WriteLine("id: " + user.id);
            Console.WriteLine("imageURL: " + user.imageURL);
            Console.WriteLine("search: " + user.search);
            Console.WriteLine("status: " + user.status);
            Console.WriteLine("username: " + user.username);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]